# How to add ADs banners in android application without using AdMob, AdSense, etc

Tags: android, ads

i just wanna add some ads banners to my applications without using some ad SDK like AdMob, AdSense, etc. Is it possible to use a custom banner with custom code?. if somebody has an example please post it in the answer. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just make a layout to act as your banner ad and include it within your other layouts and then just add an onclick function to the banner.

Or

I use admob for my ads. Admob has "in-house ads" where you can run your ads with in your app for free. You can choose for them to display exclusively and use admob to track the statistics for which ads are being clicked and how often they are being displayed.

http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619751

Comment: Does it mean we are able to advertise anything we want, and that's none of google's business? @Woodsy

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.hercle.com if you want to serve banners from some popular products in your app.  You can sign up as an affiliate and they will provide you with offers that you can include.  When you want to add an offer to your app, you can generate a GET request through their UI that you can add to your 'on click' functionality so that the user is directed to the product site with your affiliate credentials in the URL params.  If the user ends up ordering you will get a payout based on an agreed upon price per order or percentage of the revenue.  They even provide a service for providing the image URLs if you do not want to create that.

On the web site side there is full javascript injection as well.

I have never implemented them in a phone application, but the functionality is all there and if you speak with them they could probably walk you through the process.