# dynamically changing custom view as common footer in android application

Tags: android, android-custom-view

In my android app i want to put a common footer for all the activities. I created a custom view which extends Relative Layout, which contains a ImageView. It'll change the source for every 10 sec depends upon the data from server. I had put my custom view class in every activity's XML file also.
 Now my problem is, i'm unable to find the way how it will instantiated in every activity means how the result view will added to every activity.
Simply, i want Admob Advertisement like feature in my application.

This is One of my Activities XML layout:
**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
     >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="____"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
  ----
  ----


    </RelativeLayout>
     <com.ninepstudio.movieme.activities.Banner
            android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/activity_movies_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use <include
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      layout="@layout/footer" />

Comment: I want to know how to Instantiate custom view in every activity, I need only one instance of that custom view

Comment: what i did is to put it in every xml file i want it to appear if that is what you mean

Comment: I'm unable to get the solution...Can any one tell me the proper way in detail!

Comment: If u can't understand my question, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10882728/2385692)  contains almost similar thing. Need some solution

Comment: my solution was the same with the answer given there read it again

Comment: @SatineKainne I tried include also. But i'm confused, whether the changes of that Footer i.e custom view reflects in Activity automatically or not. And also, how to instantiate custom view in every activity i don't know it really required or not. I thought Single Instance of custom view only have to all the things like Request for new data and all the activities just use it.My way of thinking may be wrong, but it only happens in iOS SharedInstance.

Comment: when you put it on the activity it will reflect there so you put it on all your activities so all will show the same thats how i will solve your problem

Comment: user, can you please show some code snippet how did you manage to solve your problem? I'm having similar situation